# No rule to make target - makefile

Tags: c, makefile

This is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -O2 -Wall -fcommon -I./INC

#umiestnenie zdrojakov kniznice
SRC_LIB_DIR=SRC_LIB

#automateicke generovanie zdrojakov kniznice
SRC_LIB := $(wildcard $(SRC_LIB_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ_LIB=$(SRC_LIB:.c=.o)

#meno vykonatelneho programu
EXECUTABLE=test_rx test_tx
#vymenovanie zdrojakov aplikacie
SRC_EXE=demo_rx.c demo_tx.c
OBJ_EXE=$(SRC_EXE:.c=.o)

all: $(SRC_EXE) $(SRC_LIB) $(EXECUTABLE)

%: %00.o 
    $(CC) -o $@ $+ 

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE).exe *.o *.a SRC_LIB/*.o
```

The folder looks like this:

```
example_RS232
      |__INC (rs232.h, example_modified_rs232.h)
      |__SRC_LIB (rs232.c, example_modified_rs232.c)
      |__demo_rx.c
      |__demo_tx.c
      |__makefile
```

Compiled in C in mingw on Windows.I'm trying to compile the demo_rx.c and demo_tx.c files into the test_rx and test_tx executables. I get an error when compiling:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'test_tx', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

I don't know why I have got this error.

Comment: What version of make do you use? I mean what dialect and so on.

Comment: I doubt that this is _your_ make file. BTW, `.c.o:` rule have no files it depends on. You may start editing the rule.

Comment: Delete all the recipes except `all` and `clean`.  There's no point in trying to explicitly define the implicit rules that make will use if you omit them from the Makefile.

Comment: `.c.o` is a perfectly correct rule.  It's a suffix rule, which is the original way make created implicit rules.  It's dated, rigid, and less capable, but it does work.

Comment: You can't delete the rule to link the final target, because there's no built-in make rule that will build a file `foo` from an object file `foo00.o`.  If you want to do this you HAVE to declare a rule for that.

Comment: I do agree, though, that it's best to delete the rule to build `.o` files from `.c` files (the `.c.o` rule) and just use the built-in rules for that.

Comment: @MadScientist And what about `$<`? Do the magic replaces text automagically?

Comment: As we touch the various `make` dialects and rules(that are not compatible between make versions), I want to add some advice on the topic. If you just compile a bunch of files, why don't you just write plain dumb makefile? Throw away your magic rules.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question.  Do you mean, do automatic variables like `$<` work for suffix rules like `.c.o`?  Yes, they do.  In fact all automatic variables work for suffix rules in all versions of make: that's the oldest, most portable way to write an implicit rule: they are the "OG" implicit rule.

Comment: I have created an identical makefile file for similar programs and it works for me. I just wanted to edit it for this given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should try to never use "match-anything" rules.  A match-anything rule is a rule where the target is just `%`.  That rule can (as the name implies) match ANY target.  It could match `foo`, `foo.o`, `foo.c`, `foo.h`, or any other thing anywhere in the makefile.

This makes these types of rules REALLY inefficient as make has to consider this rule, and the prerequisites, etc. for every target.  It's also easy to get into loops this way.

Because of this, make installs a whole bunch of extra restrictions on match-anything rules that don't exist for other pattern rules.  You can [read all about this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html) in the GNU make manual discussion but the best take-away is, "don't use them".

I recommend you replace this with a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html):

```
$(EXECUTABLE) : %: %00.o 
        $(CC) -o $@ $+
```

Comment: Interesting thought. I didn't know about such issues with '%'. I changed the makefile file according to your assignment but it lists me: make: *** No rule to make target 'test_rx.o', needed by 'test_rx'.  Stop.

Comment: Well, do you have a `test_rx.c`?  According to your description, it's named `demo_rx.c`.  How is make supposed to understand that it should compile a file named `demo_rx.c` into a file named `test_rx.o`?